# How to scale and color the *-plotmark in scatter plot using pgfplots in conjunction with a colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

What I have right now:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}



\pgfplotstableread{
     A B C
     0 5 -1
     0.5 2 0
     1 7 1
     1.5 11 1.5
}\mytable %


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar
]

\addplot[scatter, only marks, scatter src=explicit, mark=*,scatter/@pre marker code/.append style=
                {/tikz/mark size={1+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/650}}]
    table[meta expr=abs(\thisrow{C})] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

What I would like to achive:

- Remove the dark circle around the filled ones.
- Make the second dot (the one that has a `meta value` of `0`) have a diameter equal to a line with option `ultra thick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `scatter/use mapped color` can be used to change the draw color of the marks to the same as the fill color. (The value `none` did not work.)

The line width of `ultra thick` is 1.6 pt. The default draw line width is 0.4 pt. The the value of the size (radius) of the mark should be set to (1.6 pt - 2 * 0.4 pt/2)/2 = 0.6 pt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
     A B C
     0 5 -1
     0.5 2 0
     1 7 1  
     1.5 11 1.5
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar 
]

\addplot[
  scatter,
  only marks,
  scatter src=explicit,
  mark=*,
  scatter/use mapped color={
    draw=mapped color,
    fill=mapped color,
  },
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style=
                {/tikz/mark size={.6pt+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/650}}]
    table[meta expr=abs(\thisrow{C})] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The drawing of the marks can be removed entirely by using a new mark type:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{filled circle}{%
  \pgfpathellipse
    {\pgfpointorigin}%
    {\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0sp}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{0sp}{\pgfplotmarksize}}%
  \pgfusepathqfill% mark=* uses \pgfusepathqfillstroke instead
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
     A B C
     0 5 -1
     0.5 2 0
     1 7 1
     1.5 11 1.5
}\mytable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar
]

\addplot[
  scatter,
  only marks,
  scatter src=explicit,
  mark=filled circle,
  mark options={draw=none},
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={%
    /tikz/mark size={.8pt+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/650},
  },
]
  table[meta expr=abs(\thisrow{C})] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Retrieval of the line width of option `ultra thick`

Option `ultra thick` is a shortcut for `line width=1.6pt`, which sets the dimen register `\pgflinewidth`. This can be used to get the value programmatically:

```
\path[ultra thick] \pgfextra{\xdef\LineWidthUltraThick{\the\pgflinewidth}};
```

or

```
\begin{scope}[ultra thick]
  \xdef\LineWidthUltraThick{\the\pgflinewidth}
\end{scope}
```